# calling draw rect does nothing sometimes

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

i have a c# form which i want to use to draw a box moving continuously across the screen

to achieve this moving box i have the following function.

```
    public void draw_forever() {
        int counter = 0;
        while (1 < 2) {
            counter += 1;
            Debug.WriteLine("yo");
            draw_rect(this, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, 1); // create a white box to clear the screen 
            draw_rect(this, counter, 150, 20, 20,0); // create a black box that moves accross the screen 
            if (counter > this.Width) { counter = 0; } // reset the box 
        }
    }
```

it does print "yo", but makes no changes to the form

here i initialize my form,  call my function and draw 1 box to the screen.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        draw_rect(this, 50, 150, 20, 20, 0); // draw a first black box
        this.Shown += (s, e) =>
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                draw_forever();
            }
        );};}
```

that 1 box i draw is all that you ever see. so we can see it never clears the screen with a white box

[image]

copy and paste the code below into a blank c# form to quickly copy what i have done

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace draw_forev
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            draw_rect(this, 50, 150, 20, 20, 0); // draw a first black box
            this.Shown += (s, e) =>
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    draw_forever();
                }
            );
            };
        }
        public static void draw_rect(Form form, int x, int y, int width, int height, int colournum) // this function draws a block
        {
            Color thecolour;
            if (colournum == 0) { thecolour = Color.Black; }
            if (colournum == 1) { thecolour = Color.White; }
            form.Paint += OnPaint;
            void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                if (colournum == 0)
                {
                    using (var Pen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 9))
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen1, x, y, width, height);
                    }
                }
                if (colournum == 1)
                {
                    using (var Pen1 = new Pen(Color.White, 9))
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen1, rect);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void draw_forever() {
            int counter = 0;
            while (1 < 2) {
                counter += 1;
                Debug.WriteLine("yo");
                draw_rect(this, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, 1); // create a white box to clear the screen 
                draw_rect(this, counter, 150, 20, 20,0); // create a black box that moves accross the screen 
                if (counter > this.Width) { counter = 0; } // reset the box 
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? You'll have to rewrite it all. To keep it simple: subscribe to the Paint event **once**, add a Timer (with Interval max 55ms), in its Tick event, add values to the Rectangle's Location (you're never doing that) then call `this.Invalidate()`. Btw, you don't need to fill the Form's ClientArea with the same Color each time, just set the BackColor in the designer. Remove `Task.Run()`, start the Timer instead.

Comment: You need to call `this.refresh();` in `draw_forever();` in order for the form to re-draw. Since you're creating a new thread, you're gonna get an exception for this. So you're gonna need a way to invoke this instead as you're then not calling it on the *creating thread*

Comment: @Jimi im never adding values to the rectangles location, 0,0 and counter, 150 are values?

Comment: @Joel i added this.refresh(); at the bottom of the while loop and it didnt throw an exception but also nothing happened

Comment: @tgm_army_2 you need to invoke it. check answer below

Comment: I stopped at `draw_forever()`. The rest is completely wrong, unreadable and the way you posted it, it wouldn't compile (it also appear that you're subscribing to the Paint event each time you call that method, OnPaint looks like it's inside another method without a Lambda, it cannot be a local function and so on). Try what I described.

Comment: @Jimi The code actually compiles

Comment: @Paul Sütterlin Does it? Well, then `void OnPaint` is just treated as a local function, but cannot be. The compiler doesn't test the logic of what you write. This method is wrong from the ground up.

Comment: @Jimi Of course you should't do it like this but it actually works.

Comment: @Paul Sütterlin It may look like it's working. But it's not. The OP will find out soon enough (when the app will start crashing *with no apparent reason*).

Comment: You've created a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine).  I say this because you write things like `while(1 < 2)` rather than `while(true)`.  Your drawing mechanism similarly seems to be intentionally designed to draw in an indirect and overly complicated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code:

First, I made the `draw_forever` method async, so you can use `await Task.Delay(55)`. If you don't use that, you couldn't see anything because your form constantly updates itself.

Then, you have to update the draw_rect method. You are only drawing the outline of the rectange, which will not clear the screen. Also i would recommend you to replace the integer colournum with an actual Color parameter. This makes the `draw_rect` method easier and the code more readable.

The third change is that you have to update the form. Use `this.Refresh()` to make sure all changes will be displayed.

Here is the new code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace draw_forev
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            draw_rect(this, 50, 150, 20, 20, Color.Black, false); // draw a first black box
            this.Shown += (s, e) =>
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    draw_forever();
                }
            );
            };
        }
        public static void draw_rect(Form form, int x, int y, int width, int height, Color colour, bool fill) // this function draws a block
        {
            form.Paint += OnPaint;
            void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                if (fill)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(colour), x, y, width, height);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(colour, 9), x, y, width, height);
                }
            }
        }

        public async void draw_forever()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (1 < 2)
            {
                counter += 1;
                Debug.WriteLine("yo " + counter);
                draw_rect(this, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, Color.White, true); // create a white box to clear the screen 
                draw_rect(this, counter, 150, 20, 20, Color.Black, false); // create a black box that moves accross the screen 
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Refresh));
                if (counter > this.Width)
                { counter = 0; } // reset the box 
                await Task.Delay(55);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Even though this code works, it is not efficent at all. You should only be subscribing to the OnPaint event once.

Comment: that probably my next task